# Regex $pattern.replace doesn't replace anything

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

The `$regexvar.Replace($var,"str",1)` isn't replacing the first instance of `"add"`

```
while(1) {
    $prompt = read-host -prompt [edit]
    if($prompt -eq "exit") {
        Write-Output("Exiting edit.")
        exit
    }
    if($prompt.StartsWith("add")) {
        $lineadd = $prompt
        [regex]$pattern = "add"
        $pattern.Replace($lineadd, "", 1)
        Add-Content -Path ".\$file" -Value "$lineadd"
        Get-Content ".\$file"
  }
}
```

When I type the following at the prompt (`[edit]:`  is the prompt message):

```
[edit]: add Test.
```

I expect the content of the output file to be:

```
 Test.
```

But it is:

```
add Test.
```

That is, no replacement was made.

Answer (score 1):

[Abdul Niyas P M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699447/abdul-niyas-p-m) has provided the crucial pointer:

- The ***return* value** of your `$pattern.Replace($lineadd, "", 1)` call **contains your result**, which is invariably a *new string*.
- .NET [strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String) are *immutable*, so by definition **there can be no .NET APIs that modify strings *in-place*** and the same therefore applies to PowerShell's string *operators*.

Therefore (simplified example):

```bash
# Sample input string.
$lineadd = 'First add, second add'

# Assign the result of the .Replace() call back to the input-string variable.
$lineadd = ([regex] 'add').Replace($lineadd, '', 1)

# Print $lineadd for diagnostic purposes
# -> 'First , second add', i.e. the first 'add' was effectively removed.
$lineadd
```

Note:

- `[regex] 'add'` constructs a [`[regex]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex) instance ad hoc - no strict need for an intermediate variable (`$pattern`).
- Since **your intent appears to be *limit how many replacements are made*** (the `1` argument in the `.Replace()` call), you indeed **need a *`[regex]`* instance's [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace) method**, given that:

  - The *`[string]`* type's [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) method (which only ever performs *literal* replacements) does *not* have this feature.

    - Conversely, if you want to ensure that your regex treats the search string *literally*, construct it via [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape); e.g.:

      ```bash
      # -> 'First , second ?'
      ([regex] [regex]::Escape('?')).Replace('First ?, second ?', '', 1)
      ```
  - Similarly, PowerShell's regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator lacks the ability to limit the number of replacements.

    - While it is still possible to achieve the same effect, assuming the number of replacements is known in advance, it requires a more complex regex and substitution expression; e.g.:

      ```bash
      # -> 'First , second add'
      'First add, second add' -replace 'add(.*)$', '$1'
      ```